# Graph API constantly returns Authorization_RequestDenied although permissions are granted

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

We are trying to use Graph API to set properties of a user account that is managed by Azure AD. The idea is that after the user completes the sign up policy our backend web API is called (by Azure AD) to set some properties that the user can't set by himself (e.g. our internal customer ID for the new user).

Unfortunately, Graph API constantly returns an exception ("Insufficient privileges tom compete this operation") when trying to send the patch request that updates the user.
I'm trying to grant the permission for all users as an admin because there is no user logged in when the accounts are updated. I basically want my application to be a third party that is able to automatically administrate user profiles.

My code looks like this:

```
public class GraphAPIClient
{
    private AuthenticationContext authContext;
    private ClientCredential clientCredential;
    private string adTenant;

    public GraphAPIClient(string tenant, string clientID, string clientSecret)
    {
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant);
        clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);
        adTenant = tenant;
    }

    public async Task<string> UpdateUserInfo(string objectID, string jsonUpdate)
    {
        return await SendPatchRequest("/users/" + objectID, jsonUpdate);
    }

    private async Task<string> SendPatchRequest(string api, string jsonRequest)
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net/", clientCredential);
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        string url = "https://graph.windows.net/" + adTenant + api + "?" + "api-version=1.6";

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), url);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
        request.Content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            object formattedError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(error);
                throw new Exception("Graph API request failed:\n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formattedError, Formatting.Indented));
        }

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

I'm using the application ID of the registered application, the tenant of the directory and the key that I have generated in Azure as a client secret. I successfully receive a token.

What I've tried:

- I have set (or I think I have) the permissions required to edit users. I've clicked "Grant Permissions" using an admin account and the permissions are displayed when viewing them in the Azure Panel:
  [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T51fy.png)
- I've set "Read and write all users' full profiles" and "Read and write directory data". Are those the right permissions for this kind of task?
- I've also tried to use the new Application Registration Console, but with that I get a "The identity of the calling application could not be established" exception when trying to get a token. The applications created in this console aren't visible in the normal Azure AD panel.

Can anyone help me with this? I've searched thoroughly, but most questions regarding this issue are older and recommend to use the old Azure panel. I've tried that and it still doesn't work and I think the new Azure panel only recently received the AD editing functionalities and didn't have them when those questions were asked.

Thank you very much – if you need any more information I'm very happy to provide it.

Comment: Have you gone through the Admin Consent workflow as well?

Comment: I don't think I have - is there a way to give admin consent either once for the entire application or automatically within the application? I'm basically looking to develop a background application that adds information to the user account that the user can't set by himself (because it is internal information that he doesn't know about). I know there are consent workflows that ask the user for consent, but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for here because it's not a third party application that tries to access an existing user account (like with Office) but our own directoy…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your scenario and code reflect the use of the **Client Credentials flow and Application Permissions**. However, you're screenshot from the Azure portal only shows Delegated permissions set up.

Depending on what kind of permissions/operations you want, you can leverage two approaches:

1. **Easiest to set up but limited set of permissions: through the Azure portal.** Ensure you select permissions from the "Application Permissions" and then click on **Grant Permissions**. If none show up that's because you've created your app as a Native application. For headless clients that will sit securely on your server side (not handed to end users) you should pick Web app / API which will give you access to application permissions:

   [image: Application permissions in Azure Portal]
2. **Hardest to set up but widest set of permissions: through PowerShell.** This is the only viable option if you want to be able to delete users. You'll need to get the ServicePrincipalID of your application and then grant the service principal the required roles as follows:

   ```
   $appDisplayName = <Your-app-display-name>

   $msolcred = Get-Credential
   Connect-MsolService -credential $msolcred

   $servicePrincipal = Get-MsolServicePrincipal | where DisplayName -eq $appDisplayName
   $objectId = $servicePrincipal.ObjectId.ToString()

   Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId 88d8e3e3-8f55-4a1e-953a-9b9898b8876b -RoleMemberObjectId $objectId -RoleMemberType servicePrincipal
   Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId 9360feb5-f418-4baa-8175-e2a00bac4301 -RoleMemberObjectId $objectId -RoleMemberType servicePrincipal
   Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId fe930be7-5e62-47db-91af-98c3a49a38b1 -RoleMemberObjectId $objectId -RoleMemberType servicePrincipal
   ```

   Alternatively, you can follow the steps in [this article.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).

Comment: "If none show up that's because you've created your app as a Native application."

**Thank you!** I've always wondered why no application permissions show up and I didn't come up with that.

It still doesn't work, though. I've set the following permissions and granted them, but I still get the exception: http://imgur.com/a/O8ktB

I once got a Bad Request error, but I think you get those if the JSON string is invalid in any case.

Comment: Nevermind – I generated a new key and it works now. Thank you so much, that really helped a lot.