# MS GraphAPI - Permissions not showing in Token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on my first application using MS Graph API, and I'm struggling with the permission configuration/usage.

**Problem description**

I'm using Postman to test my configuration before coding actual stuff, I'm accessing the API on behalf of an user (me).
I followed both those guides in the docs:

- [access on behalf of an user flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?tabs=http)
- [postman guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman)

I want to be able to:

- Read and Write calendar events, on behalf of an user
- Read the user's contacts

I configured the app and currently I have those permission set:
[image]

With this configuration, I can get an access token with postman, and with this token access the Calendar apis, but get an auth error accessing the `/people` api with this 403 response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
    }
}
```

Additionally, this gets printed in the Postman console:

> You need to add user delegated permissions in your application to at least *People.Read* in portal.azure.com and then consent as user or Grant admin consent in portal. Then, go to the Delegated folder > Authorization tab > scroll down and click on Get New Access Token button.

The configured People.Read permission do not show up in the received token:
Postman Access Token modal:

[image]

Decoded Token:

[image]

**What have I tried**

Online search for the problem do not give me relevant results, except from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583384/graph-api-constantly-returns-authorization-requestdenied-although-permissions-ar). The answer on the link got me tho this that seems to be relevant, but can't find a way to operate on the page itself:

[image]

I obviously tried to logout/login several times and re-get access tokens, still, no People.Read on the token.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you call me/people or users/{user_id}/people endpoint?

Comment: I'm calling me/people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Step 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman#step-5-get-a-delegated-access-token) in [Use Postman with the Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman) says "leave all the fields as pre-configured", including the "Scope" field, which by default is set to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`:

[image]

Using the `.default` scope value like this means the app is saying: "I would like access to the Microsoft Graph resource service (`https://graph.microsoft.com`), for whatever delegated access has been granted on behalf of the signed-in user. If no access has been granted yet, attempt to prompt the user for consent for the permissions configured on the application."

This means that as soon as *any* delegated permissions have been granted for that client app, that API, and that user, the list of requested permissions configured on the app registration is ignored entirely.

In your case, *Calendars.Read*, *Calendars.ReadWrite*, and *Calendar.ReadBasic* are already granted (but *People.Read* is *not* granted), so that's why you'll keep seeing only those three permissions, no matter how often you sign in again or get a new token.

The best thing to do here is to explicitly identify which scopes your app (or Postman, in this case) needs, by directly naming them in the "Scopes" parameter, instead of using `.default`: `https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite https://graph.microsoft.com/People.Read`.

[image]

In this case, we're identifying the target resource (API) as Microsoft Graph, with the prefix `https://graph.microsoft.com/` prefix. When the resource identifier is omitted, it is assumed to be Microsoft Graph, so you could shorten this by just asking for `Calendars.ReadWrite People.Read`:

[image]

This is the same pattern you'll want to follow when building your real app (though of course you'd be using a library such as MSAL for all the sign-in and token acquisition).